# webpack and react - ReactDom is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm trying to create a simple webpack and react webpage, and using jsx files.

I run

```
webpack serve --mode development --env development
```

and it all compiles fine, but loading the page I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

I am trying to use Emotion js, and get a simple proof-of-concept theme switching web page working.

This is my Directory Structure:

```
|-- node_modules/
|-- src/
|   |-- desktop/
|   |   |-- index.html
|   |   `-- index.jsx
|   `-- themes/
|       |-- themes.js
|       |-- default.js
|       `-- other.js
|-- www/
|-- .babelrc
|-- package.json
|-- webpack.config.js
```

I've had some troubles with the node_modules folder not being in the same folder as the src/, and it being a sibling instead.
The url also needs to be /desktop/index.html, and cannot simply be index.html

This is my index.jsx file:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

class LikeButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { liked: false };
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.liked) {
      return 'You liked this.';
    }

    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.setState({ liked: true }) }>
        Like
      </button>
    );
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
ReactDOM.render(<LikeButton />, domContainer);
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["@emotion"]
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,'www');
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,'src');
const NODE_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,'node_modules');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: path.join(SRC_DIR,"desktop/index.jsx")
  },
  output: {
    filename: "nd-js/bundle.js",
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  context: SRC_DIR,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: path.join(SRC_DIR,'desktop/index.html'),
      filename: "desktop/index.html"
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: SRC_DIR,
    open: true,
    openPage: 'desktop/index.html',
    index: 'desktop/index.html',
    compress: false,
    port: 8080
  },
}
```

My Package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "@babel/preset-stage-0": "7.8.3",
    "@emotion/babel-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "html-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
```

Looking through the produced bundle.js file when using `--mode development`, I think the problem is to do with how it incorrectly paths to the node_modules folder, as I can see this in the compiled code:

```
__webpack_require__(/*! react-dom */ \"../node_modules/react-dom/index.js\");
```

Although, that's just my best guess.

Comment: Just one question. Why??? If you're a new developer, is it not possible to use [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/)?

Comment: I tried using it, however, it messed up when adding in Emotion js.
Also, this will eventually be for updating an old system, so it needs to be as standard js and html as much as possible.

Comment: Alright, I get it. Legacy Systems are always a pain. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was me being blind, as in my index.jsx, I had mis-spelt ReactDom and ReactDOM, and so they were different.